# Python loading multiple JSON values on one line

Tags: json, python-3.x, stdin

I have a file (not a valid JSON file) that looks similar to this:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]["testing", "foo", "bar"]
```

These are two (or more), non-delimited, valid JSON values that I need to load in from STDIN. I tried just using the following (in Python 3.7):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    stripped = line.strip()
    if not stripped: break
    x = loads(stripped)
```

But that gave the error

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 118 (char 117)`

which makes sense, as it can only load one JSON value at a time. How would I go about loading in multiple of these values from STDIN when they are not delimited? Is there a way to check if the JSON loader successfully completed a load and then start another one from the same line?

Comment: Well if they are not delimeted correclty you could add a delimeter between the values manually. Or when parsing the lines, you can manually split the line into separate variables or entries in a list to parse the json individually. As for checking if it loaded successfully, you can put a try/except block around the `json.loads` part which will continue running if successful or hit the except part if an error occurs.

Comment: If it isn't valid JSON, then you cannot `json.loads` it

Comment: Personally, I would suggest the fixing the process that *generated* this file to put less burden on trying to fix it *after the fact*

Comment: I'd love to not use these files at all lol but it's basically given to me and I have no way of changing it after the fact

Comment: @AJwr if the format is always two JSON arrays in a line, with one having sub-arrays of numbers, you can develop a way to look through each line and split it into two sections for when the first JSON array ends (based on the closing `]`). It is a very manual process but would get your lines into a way that can be converted into proper JSON format.